# unable to auto fill in form with ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am stuck to auto fill in my form fields with json data via ajax call. Below are my php files.

```
<?php 
require_once('header.php');

$found_vendor=$vendor->vendor_by_id($_POST['id']);
foreach($found_vendor as $vendor_values)
{
    $email=$vendor_values['vendor_email'];
    $address=$vendor_values['vendor_address'];
    $phone=$vendor_values['vendor_phone'];
}
$response=array('email'=>$email, 'phone'=>$phone, 'address'=>$address);
echo json_encode($response);
```

i can see the json formatted string/data but on the other page the received data is not filling in the form fields. below is my file that receives the returned output from load_vendor.php file:

```
<?php 
require_once('header.php'); ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="vendor" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="click me" />
<input type="text" id="phone">
<div id="message"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#vendor').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'load_vendor.php',
            data:{id:1},
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#phone').val(data.phone);

            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the AJAX requests succeeds? If `$found_vendor` is empty/null then your `foreach` wont execute, and no values will be set

Comment: in your success write `console.log(data)` and see in the JavaScript debugger if you are getting any results

Comment: Have you checked your console , Is there any error?

Comment: Can you confirm the AJAX requests is success? And that the response 'data' is being returned? Do a console.log(data) and check your console.

Comment: i dont get anything in the console.log(data) except tons of bootstrap errors....but nothing for my request....but in the response window i can see my expected response as a json...it is as below:

Comment: {"email":"vendor@gmail.com","phone":"+97123568745","address":"XYZ Road Near Shopping Mall"}

Comment: but this is showing up in network->response window.....only

Comment: as you can see above my load_vendor.php file is 100% correct..

Comment: i did console.log(data) but nothing is showing up at all in my console....dont have a clue what may be going wrong..but as stated above i can see the json object in network->response

Comment: Do `$('#vendor').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); //...ajax call etc`. Otherwise I think it will be doing a normal postback, not an ajax call. You're not stopping the default "submit" behaviour of the button. (This is assuming the button is within a form tag in real life, which it normally would be. If not, then this might not apply). Anyway either way you should double-check whether it's making a full postback or just an ajax call. You can see easily in the network tab - if it's just ajax you get one more request, if it's a full postback it refreshes all your CSS etc as well.

Comment: thanx for response , i did that event.preventDefault() too but still console is full of only css and bootstrap junk not the full expected response...i checked my load_vendor.php on its own and it responds back 100% accurate but this ajax thing is really driving me crazy now as i have spent two days on this bloody issue and still cant seem to get out of it...

Comment: "console is full of only css and bootstrap junk". No, I suggested checking the _network tab_, not the console. The network tab will show you all the actual HTTP requests being made. Load your page normally with it open, and watch, you'll see the main PHP/HTML, and any associated JS/CSS etc all loaded. Then click to make the ajax request. You should see only _one_ extra request generated to `load_vendor.php`. nothing else. You can click into it to see what happens and what the response is. But if you see the tab refresh and all your CSS etc loading again, then it's not ajax it's a full postback

Comment: i did check the network tab and doing the same even now..n when i refresh it , comes up with all css html junk again....i do not know what is happening at all...did ajax calling before in my project 100 of times...never had this issue...but now..its really getting on my nerves...interestingly enough when i change the data type to nothing...then comes the response but it is full of css and html too....

Comment: I just noticed, in your vendor_load.php, you do `require_once('header.php');`. Let me guess, this includes a load of HTML content, right? Which you wouldn't want to return in your ajax call?

Comment: yes dear what you noticed was right....and that was causing problems. i replaced that with only the required classes and problem was resolved...thanks for being attentive and helpful...long live